# Problems using successCallback in ag-grid

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I have a vue component with ag-grid grid (infinite model). I want to access to its params to use successCallback, directly in another method in the component, after do the setDatasource.

In sum up, I can not find where the params are.

I have tried:

```js
this.gridApi.params.successCallback(data, totalRows)

this.gridOptions.params.successCallback(data, totalRows)

this.params.successCallback(data, totalRows)
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have missed the full flow of how the ag-grid operating with `dataSource`.

So according to the [official doc](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/#datasource-interface), `IDatasource` [looks](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/f065d96ee682d4c43a7275f35935d122d9faeee6/packages/ag-grid-community/src/ts/rowModels/iDatasource.ts) like that:

```
interface IDatasource {
    /** If you know up front how many rows are in the dataset, set it here. Otherwise leave blank.*/
    rowCount?: number;

    /** Callback the grid calls that you implement to fetch rows from the server. See below for params.*/
    getRows(params: IGetRowsParams): void;

    destroy?(): void;
}
```

Let's go deeply to `getRows` and `IGetRowsParams` interface (only needed part of it)

```
/** Params for the above IDatasource.getRows() */
export interface IGetRowsParams {
    ....
    successCallback(rowsThisBlock: any[], lastRow?: number): void;
    ...
}
```

So as you can see, `successCallback` only accessible via `dataSource` and exactly in `getRows` method, which means, that you don't have to get direct access via `gridAPI`. It should be defined once (as `dataSource`) and then, `ag-grid` will execute `getRows` only when it requires.

> Possible solution (not recommended to use, cut `dataSource` mostly required for infinite scroll and auto-fill the new data)

You can bind `params.successCallback` to your own property and execute it whenever you want

here is a [simple hack example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Lhpwxa9toSuajPhgZWc1?p=preview) (check `successCallbackBinding`)